# Where can I find unsaved Preview images?

Tags: memory, preview, bug, file-recovery

I have two unsaved images open in Preview. My Mac is on strike, no screen usable, but SSH is working fine. I *really* want to salvage my images.

**Where can I find my images ?**

At worst, I would accept memory dump as an option.

Comment: I have tried salvaging things with "osascript", to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Look at /Users/(your user)/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Autosave Information/
That's where mine are right now.

Comment: I do not have "~/Library/Containers". I have Mac OS X 10.6.8.